# Visual Flow new Field Rule feature

Tags: visual-workflow

I read about this new feature, which says it will work for a flow that uses Lightning runtime.

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_fieldrules.htm

I enabled Lightning Runtime for my Org using this process :

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_admin_lexruntime.htm

But I can't find the Field Rule screen as shown in the Release Notes example in my first link. Should I now be able to use the new Visual Flow Field Rule feature ? Or do I need to be completely converted to Lightning ? If I can use it without completely converted then could you tell me how to find that Field Rule screen shown in the example. I've looked all around for it within the Screen element on Flow.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered similar problem and I contacted Salesforce support that confirmed me that this functionality was part of pilot features program that was intitally scheduled to go into a formal pilot in the Spring '17 release. According to them "Field Rules for flows" (a.k.a. "Dynamic screens in Visual Workflow") pilot has not been set for implementation.
The product management team has announced that this pilot is closed and they are pursuing a different longer term direction for dynamic fields, without having any commitment on the delivery date.

Comment: Are there any links relating to the pilot closure?

Comment: Well, that doesn't help much, does it ? I don't really know what to make about that. I guess it's a matter of sitting around and waiting.....

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I am not aware about any official online communication from Salesforce. With recent releases, for our implementations, we try to use Lightning Components to implement dynamic screens in our flows (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_flow_screens_replace_form.htm). 
That I know, there might be some existing solutions that can be installed without coding for example https://medium.com/@alexedelstein/dynamic-questions-in-lightning-flow-b0269ee373ce.

Answer (score 1):

We (Salesforce) are making available as of Winter '20 the following feature which replaces Field Rules:

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_conditionals.htm?edition=&impact=

Thanks for your patience. This one is done right and here to stay.

Alex Edelstein - Flow Product Management