# Is that possible to conditional based show extra field in flow screen as same like vf page

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a business requirement to show field in the same flow screen when some check box is selected.

I don't think there is a possibility to show in one screen. We can move screen based on condition .

Any suggestion.

Comment: There's an [idea for that](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000iJIqAAM), but for today, it has to be multiple screens.

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_fieldrules.htm

Comment: @Kasper Ah. Dunno how I missed that in the release notes.

Comment: I dont see this option in the Org. Is there any special setting to be enabled

Comment: got it..
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/179115/visual-flow-new-field-rule-feature